# Defining command with asterisk

Tags: macros, xparse

I have a command which takes multiple arguments, one of which is a star:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ s m m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{Asterisk is here.}{Asterisk is not here.} #2 #3.
}
```

I would like to define another command which works like the first one, but with some predifined arguments, like

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{ s m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \foo*{#2}{a}
    }{
        \foo{#2}{a}
    }
}
```

`\baz` and `\baz*` work in the same way, so I would like to somehow define `\baz` without repeating  the `{#2}{a}` part two times. I have tried

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{ s m }{
    \expandafter\foo\IfBooleanT{#1}{*}{#2}{a}
}
```

but it doesn't work.
Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ s m m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{Asterisk is here.}{Asterisk is not here.} #2 #3.
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{ s m }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \foo*{#2}{a}
    }{
        \foo{#2}{a}
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \baz{b}

    \baz*{c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me that `\foo` here is a document command: is it intended for direct use too?

Comment: @JosephWright no, but in my document command `\foo` takes a lot of key-value options, and there is also a number of commands like `\baz`, with predeifned list of these options. Do you mean that I can just insert the defnition of `\foo` inside `\baz`?

Comment: I was getting at more that the LaTeX3 model is that document commands have stars, optional arguments, etc., whereas 'code level' commands which implement them have fixed mandatory arguments. I'm wary of passing on a star ...

Comment: @JosephWright, this is a good idea, I will probably implement it that way. Thanx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TeX works by macro expansion, there is no need to have *all* of the arguments for `\foo` in the conditional, so we can just have the unique part:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ s m m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{Asterisk is here.}{Asterisk is not here.} #2 #3.%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{ s m }{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
      {\foo*}%
      {\foo}%
        {#2}{a}%
}

\begin{document}

    \baz{b}

    \baz*{c}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've tided up line ends here: we are not in `\ExplSyntaxOn` conditions so spaces are important.